# Routing doesn't work as expected after building a react app using yarn build

Tags: reactjs, react-router, yarnpkg

I build a react app, created the routing file and it works as expected when I run the app using `yarn start`, but when I tried to build the project in order to deploy it as a static component and run it using
`npx serve -l 3000` , the routing didn't work as expected, it keeps giving me `404` when I hit any page other than the index one.

```
The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.
You may serve it with a static server:

  yarn global add serve
  serve -s build
```

```
const Routes =  () => {
    return <Router key="router">
        <Switch key="swith-router">
            <Route exact path="/" key="a">
               ...
            </Route>
            <Route path="/b" key="b">
                ...
            </Route>
            <Route path="/c" key="c">
                ...
            </Route>
            <Route path="/d" key="d">
               ...
            </Route>
            <Route path="/e" key="e">
                ...
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
};

export default Routes;
```

Comment: I don't think `serve` does any push-state routing, so that's the expected behaviour. You'd have to configure the underlying `serve-handler`, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve#configuration, https://github.com/vercel/serve-handler#rewrites-array

Comment: Thanks for your response, what do they mean by `Next, add it to your HTTP server.` ?

Comment: They mean add the handler to whatever server you're using, like in the example they immediately show or e.g. https://github.com/CodeYourFuture/proctor/blob/master/bin/server.js. In your case you should just be able to use the config file per the serve docs.